# Is mariabDB compatible with matlab?

Tags: matlab, mariadb, mariasql

I wanted to connect mariaDB to matlab on Linux OS.
I tried using the database command but it give the error ‘Unable to find database driver.’ Can you please help me out.

Comment: Which JDBC Connector is failing?  See https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: mariabdb-Java-client-2.1.2.jar is the one that is failing